# How to have public class member that can be accessed but not changed by other classes C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

This probably has been asked before, but I can't find something on it other than the general `private/public/const` solutions. Basically, I need to load fonts into an array when an instance of my `class text` is created. The `text` class is in my `text.h` file, and defined in `text.cpp`. In both of these files, they also include a `Fonts class`, and so I want my `fonts` class to have my selection of `fonts` preloaded in an array ready to be accessed by my `text` class AFTER the first instance is created. I want these fonts to be able to be **accessed** by my `text` class, but not able to be changed. I can't create a `TTF_Font *Get_Font()` method in the `fonts` class as each time a `font` is created, it loads memory that needs to be manually closed, so I couldn't exactly close it after it runs out of the method's scope,  so rather, I would want to do something like, when creating a character for example, call `TTF_RenderText_Blended(Fonts::arialFonts[10], "123", black);` which would select the font type of `arial in size 11` for example.

Comment: How about only using member *functions* to access data of your class?

Comment: If i make a function called ```Get_Font()``` it has to be of type ```TTF_Font*``` which is stores memory that does not get ```free'd``` after it runs out of scope (I'm pretty sure, had this thing where memory usage kept increasing) and so to get rid of the memory it uses you have to call ```TTF_CloseFont(font)```

Comment: You could use a wrapper class for fonts (possibly that could be converted to `TTF_Font*`) and whose destructor calls `TTF_CloseFont`. As a general tip: Try to abstract out all low-level details of the API you're using.

Comment: That's a ton of verbiage that could've been expressed more concisely as a small amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what type of application you are using your fonts in, but I've done some 3D graphics programming using OpenGL and Vulkan. This may or may not help you, but should give you some kind of context on the structure of the framework that is commonly used in Game Engine development.

Typically we will have a Texture class or struct that has a vector of color triplets or quads that represent the color data for each pixel in the image. Other classes will contain UV coordinates that the texture will be applied to... We also usually have functions to load in textures or graphics files such as PNG, JPG, TGA, etc. You can write your own fairly trivially or you can use many of the opensource loader libraries that are out there if you're doing graphics type programming. The texture class will contain other properties such as mipmap, if it is repeated or mirrored, its quality, etc... So we will typically load a texture and assign it an ID value and will store it into a hash table. If this texture is trying to be loaded again from a file, the code will recognize that it exists and exits that function call, otherwise it will store this new texture into the hash table.

Since most rendered texts are 2D, instead of creating a 3D model and sending it to the render to be processed by the model-view-projection matrix... We create what is commonly called a Sprite. This is another class. It has vertices to make up its polygonal edges. Typically a sprite will have 4 vertices since it is a QUAD. It will also have texture coordinates that will be associated with it. We don't apply the textures directly to the sprite because we want to instance a single sprite having only a single copy in memory. What we will typically do here, is we will send a reference of it to the renderer along with a reference to the texture by id, and transformation matrix to changes its shape, size, and world position. When this is being processed by the GPU through the shaders, since it is a 2D object, we use an orthographic projection. So this saves a matrix multiplication within the vertex shader for every vertex. Basically, it will be processed by the view-projection matrix. Here our Sprites will be stored similarly to our textures, in a hash table with an associated ID.

Now we have a sprite that is basically a Graphics Image that is drawn to the screen, a simple quad that can be resized and placed anywhere easily. We only need a single quad in memory but can draw hundreds even thousands because they are instanced via a reference count.

How does this help with Text or Fonts? You want your Text class to be separate from your Font class. The text class will contain where you want to draw it, which font to use, the size of the font, the color to be applied, and the text itself... The Font class would typically inherit from the basic Sprite Class.

We will normally create a separate tool or mini- console program that will allow you to take any of the known true type fonts or windows fonts by name that will generate 2 files for you. You will pass flags into the program's command-line arguments along with other commands such as -all for all characters or -"abc123" for just the specific characters you want, and -12, for the font size, and by doing so it will generate your needed files. The first will be a single textured image that we call a Font Atlas which is basically a specific form of a Sprite Sheet and the other file will be a CSV text file with generated values for texture positioning of each character's quad.

Back in the main project, the font class will load in these two files the first is simple as it's just a Texture image which we've already done before, and the later is the CSV file for the information that is needed to generate all of the appropriate quads, however, the "Font" class does have quite a bit of complex calculations that need to be performed. Again, when a Font is loaded into memory, we do the same as we did before. We check to see if it is already loaded into memory by either filename or by id and if it isn't we then store it into a hash table with a generated associated ID.

Now when we go to use the Text class to render our text, the code might look something like this:

```
void Engine::loadAssets() {   
    // Textures
    assetManager_.loadTexture( "assets\textures\shells.png" );
    assetManager_.loadTexture( "assets\textures\blue_sky.jpg" );
    
    // Sprites
    assetManager_.loadSprite( "assets\sprites\jumping_jim.spr" );
    assetManager_.loadSprite( "assets\sprites\exploading_bomb.spr" );
    
    assetManager_.loadFont( "assets\fonts\"arial.png", 12 );
    // Same font as above, but the code structure requires a different font id for each different size that is used.
    assetManager_.loadFont( "assets\fonts\"arial.png", 16 ); 
    assetManager_.loadFont( "assets\fonts\"helvetica.png" );
}
```

Now, these are all stored as a single instance in our AssetManager class, this class containers several hashtables for each of the different types of assets. Its role is to manage their memory and lifetime. There is only ever a single instance of each, but we can reference them 1,000 times... Now somewhere else in the code, we may have a file with a bunch of standalone `enumerations`...

```
enum class FontType {
    ARIAL,
    HELVETICA,
};
```

Then in our render call or loadScene function....

```
void Engine::loadScene() {
    fontManager_.drawText( ARIAL, 18, glm::vec3(-0.5, 1.0, 0.5), glm::vec4(245, 169, 108, 128), "Hello World!"); 
    fontManager_.drawText( ARIAL, 12, glm::vec3(128, 128, 0), glm::vec4(128, 255, 244, 80), "Good Bye!");
}
```

The drawText function would be the one that takes the `ARIAL` id and gets the reference into the hashtable for that stored font. The renderer uses the positioning, and color values, the font size, and the string message... The ID and Size are used to retrieve the appropriate Font Atlas or Sprite Sheet. Then each character in the message string will be matched and the appropriate texture coordinates will be used to apply that to a quad with the appropriate size based on the font's size you specified.

All of the file handling, opening, reading from, and closing of was already previously done in the `loadAssets` function. All of the required information is already stored in a set of hashtables that we reference in to via instancing. There is no need or concern to have to worry about memory management or heap access at this time, this is all done through utilizing the cache. When we draw the text to the screen, we are only manipulating the pixels through the shaders by matrix transformations.

There is another major component to the engine that hasn't been mentioned yet, but we typically use a Batch Process and a Batch Manager class which handles all of the processing for sending the Vertices, UV Coordinates, Color, or Texture Data, etc... to the video card. CPU to GPU transfer across the buss and or the PCI-Express lanes are considered slow, we don't want to be sending 10,000, 100,000, or even 1 million individual render calls every single frame! So we will typically create a set of batches that has a priority queue functionality and when all buckets are full, either the bucket with the highest priority value or the fullest bucket will be sent to the GPU and then emptied. A single bucket can hold 10,000 - 100,000 primitives... where single a primitive could be a point, a line, a triangle list, a triangle fan, etc... This makes the code much more efficient. The heap is seldom used. The BatchManager, AssetManager, TextureManager, AudioManager, FontManager classes, etc. are the ones that live on the heap, but all of their stored assets are used by reference and due to that we can instance a single object a million times! I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Yeah, it helps a bunch. Thanks, thats quite an extensive answer